# How to add Icon in Android Application ?

Tags: android

I have seen in android native Email application that it updates the icon by showing how many new mails are there ?
Is it a service that updates the icon or is it a process who does it ?
Can someone tell me which file does this change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done from the application. There are two ways that I know of to achieve that:

- A widget that updates itself and changes its icon (but it's not a regular icon to an app)
- Some launchers do that on regular icons (e.g. **GoLauncher**) but they do that from the launcher application code itself: they have a plugin that checks for pre-defined services (mail, Gmail, text messages, missed phone calls, etc.) and then draw a little notification on top of the application icon.

Comment: @Chetan, Yes, it's using widgets instead of normal icons, so this is the first method

Comment: Can you please provide me some hint about how to develop this ?Any proper link will also do for me.

Comment: Use onUpdate method on your widget, and change the icon to something that indicates the new status, look at that for example (there are many more examples right here on StackOverflow) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977017/changing-a-widgets-icon-from-onupdate

Answer (score 0):

There is no line of code that can do that, at least not in Gingerbread...
What you can do (and that's what most applications that do that use) is create a 1x1 widget that updates its "number of events" whenever an event occurs.

for some information about widgets and remoteViews you can go to:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html

or just google it...

Comment: It's not an widget it is just an icon on which it shows how many new mails are arrived ?